# how to ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION keeping GPS turned OFF?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I would like to get accurate location from `NETWORK_PROVIDER` keeping GPS turned OFF in order to save battery. This seems impossible becasue android, when `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is specified, turns on GPS even when location is not requested to GPS_PROVIDER.

I have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

into the Manifest. I needed that in order to avoid android obfuscating accurate position.

I registered updates just using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and not `GPS_PROVIDER`:

```
myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
        60000, 0, locationListener);
```

GPS turns on anyhow. How can I avoid it (without forcing the user to disable GPS, that actually works but is undesired)?

Comment: Use this method and check whether your provider is using GPS or not.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#requiresSatellite()

Answer (score 2):

Sounds strange, if you haven't requested location updates from the gps-provider, it shouldn't boot up the GPS.

Let me give you a piece of advice though - don't count on the network provider to give you 'fine' accuracy unless you're sitting on a wifi that google knows the position of.

Positioning based on cell towers usually have accuracy of about 500 - 2000m, perhaps 3-500m in city centers.

Answer (score 0):

Use either [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) is you want GPS to be used or [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) if you don't want to use GPS.

Answer (score 0):

If your positioning technologies are disabled to save power, how can you expect to get an accurate position?  That would be like expecting a car to take you to work but not wanting to put gas in it. tanstaafl.

As mentioned above, WiFi positioning can give you pretty good location acuracy if you are around a couple of APNs that Google knows about.  Given enough time and enough people using their phones, Google will eventually learn every APN that doesn't move.